# Having a maximum flow in a transportation network, find the maximum flow for the same network if exactly 1 edge changes its capacity.

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

[image]

[image]

I have an idea for the c) problem, finding an augmenting path from network R to network R1, and then applying the same procedure until i get the maximum flow for Rp, its similar to what Ford_Fulkerson does, but i have no idea how to approach d). Please, help me!

Comment: Don't you just have to "update" the flow rate of the edge in question, assuming net flow rate is the arithmetic sum of the component flow rates (like water flow rates in pipes)?

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE! Please reformat your question by typing the information as opposed to using images (since they can be hard to read), and then using mathjax to reformat the rest of your question. You will find people to be more helpful in that case.

Comment: The aim of the exercise its not to run an algorithm like Ahuja-Orlin, Ford Fulkerson, E.K ..., but to make some observation on how from having the maximum flow of a network R0, to get the maximum flow of R1, then applying the same procedure from R1 to R2, R2 to R3 ... R(p-1) to RP